Why is the union of working parts in the Hechler forcing a well-defined function?
Source: Set Theory, Third Edition by Thomas Jech.
Definition (Hechler Forcing): Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a given family of functions $h: \omega\to\omega$. A forcing condition is a pair $p=(s, E)$, where $s=\langle s(0), \dots, s(n-1)\rangle$ is a finite sequence of natural numbers and $E$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{G}$. A condition $(s', E')$ is stronger than $(s, E)$ if:
(i) $s\subset s'$, and $E\subset E'$;
(ii) if $k\in \text{dom}(s')-\text{dom}(s)$, then $s(k)>h(k)$ for all $h\in E$.
Note that $(P, <)$ is c.c.c. Now, let $G\subset P$ be generic; we let $\mathbf{f=\bigcup\{s: (s, E)\in G\ \text{for some}\ E\}}$. We claim that $\mathcal{G}$ is eventually dominated by $f$. Let $h\in\mathcal{G}$ be arbitrary. First there is a condition $\mathbf{(s, E)\in G}$ such that $\mathbf{h\in E}$ (by genericity). Secondly, ...
My Questions:
(1) Why is $f=\bigcup\{s: (s, E)\in G\ \text{for some}\ E\}$ a (well-defined) function? What if, for example, we have $s_1=\langle0, 1, 2\rangle$ and $s_2=\langle2, 1, 0\rangle$ for some $(s_1, E_1), (s_2, E_2)\in G$?
(2) How does "there is a condition $(s, E)\in G$ such that $h\in E$" follow from genericity exactly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.


If $(s,E)$ and $(s',E')$ are compatible conditions, then either $s$ is an initial segment of $s',$ or vice versa, so all the $s$ such that $(s,E)\in G$ are compatible, and union to a function.

Just from the rules of what constitutes a stronger condition... for any $h\in \mathcal G$ and $(s,E)\in P,$ we have $(s,E\cup\{h\})\le (s,E).$ So the conditions with $h\in E$ are dense.



I completely forgot what a filter is...
